# Alloacation on stack inside function

Tags: c++, memory-management

Is data allocated on stack inside a function cleared when the function ends? The following code gives me an error (program terminates with 0xC00000FD exception code):

```
void fun()
{
    const long len = (1024 * 1024) / 4; // 1 MB
    int aa[len]{};
}

int main()
{
    fun();
    const long len = (1024 * 1024) / 4; // 1 MB
    int aa[len]{};
}
```

If I do not call fun() at the beginning it works fine.

Also, what is a default stack size using MinGW?

Comment: *"gives me an error"* - which error?

Comment: The program just terminates with 0xC00000FD exception code.

Comment: That is a funny one for this site! `0xC00000FD` is a stack overflow!

Comment: Typically one should aim at 4KB stack size (even though it may be much larger).

Comment: Try here for a description of: [0xC00000FD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18721841/10871073).

Comment: I believe the problem is that with a 1MB stack you can't put a single 1MB variable on the stack you need a slightly larger stack.

Comment: it's about compile time and run time constant for array's length
you can use direct initialization if you use C++11  const long len {(1024 * 1024) / 4}; or use #define to set len

Comment: The question is also about will the memory for array inside function foo be allocated before function foo will be called (in compile time) or when the function gets called? Will the memory for this array be relased when the function will end? Assume that we will use small array, e.g. of 10 elements.